# Using Bootstrap Validation with ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and the http://formvalidation.io/ Validation module. I have read the examples regarding ASP.NET and Bootstrap integration, however I a having issues when submitting the form.

I want the button to ensure all client side validation is correct before it completes a postback. Currently I can only seem to do 1 or the other.

Here is my submit button markup:

`<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSend" runat="server" Text="Send" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" UseSubmitBehavior="false"  ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick="return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Send</asp:LinkButton>`

The above code validates the form correctly, but doesn't fire the event from the code behind (Due to the return false; in OnClientClick).

If I remove 'return false;' then the event fires regardless of the client validation.

My question is, what should I be using in the OnClientClick to validate the page and then fire the event providing the form is valid?

Appreciate any help, you may have guessed I'm not too great with JS and have googled for days

Thanks,
Steve                           `

Comment: you have used `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` remove that and try.

Comment: I have already tried it without it, and it still provides the same problem. The page seems to post back, but the event in the code behind isn't fired.

Comment: what event you are having in code behind.

Comment: I currently just have code to hide the form and display a success message, 2 placeholders... But it will have the code to send an email off. `        plcContactForm.Visible = False
        plcSuccess.Visible = True1

Comment: which event it is? submit or click

Comment: OnClick, there isn't a submit event in ASP.NET to my knowledge.

Comment: Here it is:
    Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        plcContactForm.Visible = False
        plcSuccess.Visible = True
    End Sub

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: i did not see `btnSend_Click` event in your `<asp:LinkButton`.  You should have `OnClick="btnSend_Click"` in your view.

Comment: Hi, you don't need that in vb.net you can have a Handles btnSend.click in the vb code.